# How to include jQuery when no header and footer on the page

Tags: jquery

I have a plugin page, which doesn't have `header.php` or `footer.php`. How can I include Wordpress jQuery on this page so I can use syntax like below ?

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function()
  {
      alert('hello');
  });
```

At the moment it says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: Is the plugin page in admin area or in front end? Please provide a bit more details.

Comment: As @VinodDalvi said, this question lacks context. For example why exactly the page lacks calls to `header.php`

Comment: looks like you are trying to define jquery.min.js, in the header.php of the theme or in the header/footer section when page loads so your script will run Right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though uncommon, you can use `wp_print_scripts( ['jquery'] )` for explicit output.

Note that you might hit issues with hooks firing in unexpected ways and such. *Generally* all WP pages on front end should just implement header/footer properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();` if you're putting all html in just one file.

Although I would suggest making custom header for your plugin page. Which will have `<head>`, `<html>` and other necessary tags. Same with footer. `eg. header-plugin.php` and the use `get_header('plugin');`